# Redshift permission denied on Federated Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, federated-queries

I am trying to query a Federated Table in Redshift with a user different from the one who created the Federated Schema and Table.

Of course I get a

```
permission denied for relation my_federated_table
```

so it is the case to grant the right permissions.

The syntax to create a Federated Schema is quite similar to the one used for External Schemas on S3 but when it comes to grant permission on the Federated Schema it is different.

So I tried

```
grant select on my_federated_schema.my_federated_table to my_user;
```

But I get

```
[0A000] ERROR: Operation not supported on external tables
```

Also I've been looking for documentation online around it but no luck.

Any ideas on how to grant access to a Federated Table?

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, eventually granting access to the Federated Schema as follows allows the user to run Federated Queries:

```
grant usage on schema my_federated_schema to my_user;
```